# Is it possible to overwrite node module path?

Tags: node.js

Suppose I have a project structure like this:

```
 project
  -src
    index.js
   -functions
      bar.js
```

My `index.js` looks like this

```
import bar from '../functions/bar`

bar()
```

Is it possible to create an alias for `functions` dir, so that my import would like this:

```
import bar from `mocks/bar`
```

Comment: Link the files?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, e.g., https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias, or off the project's root path, or... etc.

Comment: TypeScript supports this out of the box, if that's an option. https://decembersoft.com/posts/say-goodbye-to-relative-paths-in-typescript-imports/

Comment: @naeramarth7 no, as my project only has .js files which I don't want to overwrite using TS